# ListBoxItem in WPF - scale animation when selected

Tags: wpf, animation, triggers, listbox, listboxitem

I have a `ListBox` with customized item's style. I want the item to grow a bit when selected, and go back to its original size when deselected. I've tried several solutions but none seemed to work. I think the problem lies in the proper setting of `Storyboard.TargetProperty`.

My current XAML looks like this:

```
...
<ListBox.Resources>                   
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                <Trigger.EnterActions>
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="LayoutTransform.(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)" To="1.2" Duration="0:0:.3" AutoReverse="True"/>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </Trigger.EnterActions>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</ListBox.Resources>
...
```

---

**My final code (with answers applied):**

```
...
<ListBox.Resources>                   
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
        <Setter Property="RenderTransformOrigin" Value="0.5,0.5" />
        <Setter Property="RenderTransform">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ScaleTransform />
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                <Trigger.EnterActions>
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.ScaleX" To="1.1" Duration="0:0:.1" />
                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.ScaleY" To="1.1" Duration="0:0:.1" />
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </Trigger.EnterActions>
                <Trigger.ExitActions>
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.ScaleX" To="1.0" Duration="0:0:.1" />
                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.ScaleY" To="1.0" Duration="0:0:.1" />
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </Trigger.ExitActions>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</ListBox.Resources>
...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using following code:

```
...
<ListBox.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
        <Setter Property="LayoutTransform">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ScaleTransform x:Name="scaleTransform" />
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                <Trigger.EnterActions>
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="LayoutTransform.ScaleX" To="1.2" Duration="0:0:.3" AutoReverse="True"/>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </Trigger.EnterActions>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</ListBox.Resources>
...
```

Comment: Thank you! Do you happen to know how to make it scale around the item's center? Setting `<ScaleTransform CenterX="0.5" CenterY="0.5" />` doesn't work.

Comment: Use a `RenderTransform` instead of a `LayoutTransform` and set the `RenderTransformOrigin` to `0.5,0.5`.